# ReInitialize twitter-fabric

Tags: android, twitter-fabric

In MainActivity I use CrashLytic

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     if (!newUser){
           if (!Fabric.isInitialized()) 
                    Fabric.with(context, new Crashlytics());
     } else {

        goToRegistrationFrame();

     }        
   }
```

I switch Fragment by this code, when User try to  restore his account
and I'm trying to reload application

```
Intent i = getActivity().getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                        .getLaunchIntentForPackage(getActivity().getBaseContext().getPackageName());
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);
```

After reload Application it's starting from registration fragment where I'm using Digits, and setting up new Fabric parameters

```
Fabric.with(getActivity(), new TwitterCore(authConfig),
                new Digits.Builder().withTheme(R.style.CustomDigitsTheme).build());
```

But unfortunatly I see that Fabric.isInitialized() is TRUE, and as a result when I call :

```
Digits.authenticate(authConfigBuilder.build());
```

I've got this exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.digits.sdk.android.AuthClient com.digits.sdk.android.Digits.getAuthClient()' on a null object reference
```

My quesyion is:

1. How to reinitialize Fabric, I know that the problem is that Fabric was setted before and not cleaned whet application was reloaded.
2. Or how to reloadd application to get the same result and Fabric was not be initialized when I switch to new Fragment.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I've found only one way, just reload app by this decisison
https://github.com/JakeWharton/ProcessPhoenix